# Import GML data in SQL Server Spatial

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database, fme-form, import, gml

I have GML file with Application Schema whose data I need to import into SQL Server Spatial. I have been creted database structure with all thing that I need in database, and now I need to fill it with GML data.

How is this possible?

**EDIT:**

Does the SQLServer has some option to insert GML itself, or I need to use some other software like FME?